# Is there any package that contains NFL football data?

Tags: r

I have come across the R `baseball` package containing basically the entire historical scope of professional baseball data that can be used for fantasy analysis. Does anyone know if something similar exists for NFL football data?

I know of some previous answers that mention sites such as www.pro-football-reference.com that give data on every player, but I am looking for something in an aggregate, data frame format.

Comment: When you say baseball package do you mean Lahman (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Lahman/index.html) package?

Answer (score 3):

A quick google for `NFL football csv data` lead to a number of interesting links, for example [this one](http://www.repole.com/sun4cast/data.html), or [this one](http://codeandfootball.wordpress.com/tag/csv/). [This link](http://www.phys.utk.edu/sorensen/cfr/cfr/SportsRanking.html) also looks promising.

Answer (score 2):

NFLdata.com has a complete historical database, and weekly updates during the season.  There might be some other decent sites out there that sell the data, but base on my experience, these guys are the best.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Now there is: https://github.com/maksimhorowitz/nflscrapR 
It scrapes NFL data from the NFL website. It contains play-by-play data for all games since 2009.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at http://www.fantasydata.com

They have a restful api for NFL MLB NBA and NHL
Has real time stats during games.
Not free though is a paid service.